# Combining multiple arrays or ranges into one

Tags: google-sheets

Does Google Sheets support any way to combine multiple arrays or ranges into one?

I am looking to combine two data ranges when making a call to [FREQUENCY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094286) function. For example:

```
=FREQUENCY(B5:F50; I5:I16)
=FREQUENCY(J5:N50; I5:I16)
```

work great on their own but I would like them to be combined into a single function call. Something like MS Excel equivalent `=FREQUENCY((B5:F50, J5:N50), I5:I16)`.

Of course I can just reshuffle columns where I have both datasets side-by-side to reference them with `=FREQUENCY(B5:K50; I5:I16)` but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
=frequency({B5:F50;J5:N50};I5:I16)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it there is no solution to my question. I've tried an array of options that work in MS Excel but Google Spreadsheets seem to be a different animal.

As a solution I had to modify my spreadsheet code display columns from two different datasets side-by-side.